# Why does the appended object not appear in my swiftUI view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, observable

I'm trying to create an app in swiftUI for a card game but when I ask the player to draw a card from an onTapGesture, then card gets added to the player's hand but is not reloaded in the View. The player is an observable object and the hand is a published variable.

Below is the player view class and all the helper functions to reorder the cards by dragging and dropping.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardData: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    var card: Card?
}

class HandModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [CardData]
    var hand: [Card]?
    
    let row = [
        GridItem(.fixed(90))
        
    ]
    
    init() {
        self.hand = nil
        self.data = []
    }
        
    
    func setHand(hand: [Card]) {
        self.hand = hand
        
        data = Array(repeating: CardData(id: 0, card:nil), count: hand.count)
        for i in 0..<data.count {
            data[i] = CardData(id: i, card: hand[i])
        }
    }
}

struct PlayerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var player: Player
    var deck: Deck
    var discardPile: [Card]
    @State private var ruleChecker: GameRules = GameRules()
    @State private var selectedCards: [Image] = []
    @State private var didTap: Bool = false
    private var yoffset: CGFloat {
        return didTap ? -15.0 : 0.0
    }
    var myCard: Card = Card(cardSuit: "", cardNum: 1, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 1)
    @StateObject private var handModel = HandModel()
    @State private var dragging: CardData?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(player.getName()).font(.largeTitle).bold().onAppear{
                handModel.setHand(hand: player.getHand())
            }
            
            LazyHGrid(rows: [GridItem(.fixed(90))], spacing: 5) {
                HStack {
                    Image(discardPile.first?.getCardImage() ?? Card(cardSuit: "", cardNum: 0, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 0).getCardImage()).resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: CGFloat(cardWidth))
                    
                    Image("cardBack_red5").resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: CGFloat(cardWidth)).onTapGesture{
                        player.drawCard(deck: deck)
                        for card in player.getHand() {
                            card.Print()
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            LazyHGrid(rows: handModel.row, spacing: 5) {
                ForEach(handModel.data) { d in
                    CardItemView(d: d)
                        .overlay(dragging?.id == d.id ? Color.white.opacity(0.8) : Color.clear)
                        .onDrag {
                            self.dragging = d
                            return NSItemProvider(object: String(d.id) as NSString)
                        }
                        .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DragRelocateDelegate(item: d, listData: $handModel.data, current: $dragging))
                }
            }.animation(.spring(), value: handModel.data)
        }
    }
}


struct PlayerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PlayerView(player: Player(hand: [Card(cardSuit: "Hearts", cardNum: 9, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 10), Card(cardSuit: "Hearts", cardNum: 8, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 10), Card(cardSuit: "Hearts", cardNum: 7, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 5), Card(cardSuit: "Spades", cardNum: 3, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 5), Card(cardSuit: "Clubs", cardNum: 5, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 5), Card(cardSuit: "Spades", cardNum: 2, isSpecial: true, pointValue: 25), Card(cardSuit: "Spades", cardNum: 13, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 10), Card(cardSuit: "Diamonds", cardNum: 8, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 10), Card(cardSuit: "Diamonds", cardNum: 12, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 10), Card(cardSuit: "Diamonds", cardNum: 1, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 15), Card(cardSuit: "Clubs", cardNum: 3, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 5), Card(cardSuit: "Clubs", cardNum: 3, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 5)], name: "Nati", placement: 0), deck: Deck(suit: ["Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades"], num_of_cards_per_suit: 13, num_of_special_card: 4), discardPile: [Card(cardSuit: "Clubs", cardNum: 10, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 10)])
        
        
    }
}

struct DragRelocateDelegate: DropDelegate {
    let item: CardData
    @Binding var listData: [CardData]
    @Binding var current: CardData?
    
    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        if item != current {
            let from = listData.firstIndex(of: current!)!
            let to = listData.firstIndex(of: item)!
            if listData[to].id != current!.id {
                listData.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: from),
                              toOffset: to > from ? to + 1 : to)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        return DropProposal(operation: .move)
    }
    
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        self.current = nil
        return true
    }
}

//CardItem

struct CardItemView: View {
    var d: CardData
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            CardView(card: d.card ?? Card(cardSuit: "", cardNum: 0, isSpecial: false, pointValue: 0))
        }
       
    }
}
struct DropOutsideDelegate: DropDelegate {
    @Binding var current: CardData?
    
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        current = nil
        return true
    }
}
```

I know the card is being added to the hand, but it does not appear when I run the code. Below are the player, deck and card classes.

```
class Player: ObservableObject {
    @Published var hand: [Card]
    ...
    func drawCard(deck: Deck) -> Void {
        hand.append(deck.getTopCard())
    }
}
class Deck {
    var deck = [Card]()
    ...
    func getTopCard() -> Card {
        let x: Card = deck[0]
        deck.remove(at: 0)
        return x
    }
}
class Card: Comparable, Identifiable, ObservableObject, Codable {
    
    var cardNum:Int
    var cardSuit:String
    var specialCard:Bool
    var pointValue:Int
    @Published var selected:Bool
    var id = UUID()
    
    init(cardSuit:String, cardNum:Int, isSpecial:Bool, pointValue:Int) {
        self.cardNum = cardNum
        self.cardSuit = cardSuit
        self.specialCard = isSpecial
        self.pointValue = pointValue
        self.selected = false
        
    }
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case selected
        case cardNum
        case cardSuit
        case specialCard
        case pointValue
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        selected = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .selected)
        cardNum = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .cardNum)
        cardSuit = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .cardSuit)
        specialCard = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .specialCard)
        pointValue = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .pointValue)
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(selected, forKey: .selected)
    }
    
    
    
    func getCardImage() -> String {
        
        var imageName : String = ""
        if cardSuit == "joker"{
            imageName = "cardJoker"
        }
        else {
            if cardNum > 1 && cardNum < 11 {
                imageName = "card" + cardSuit + String(cardNum)
            } else {
                if cardNum == 1 {
                    imageName = "card" + cardSuit + "A"
                } else if cardNum == 11 {
                    imageName = "card" + cardSuit + "J"
                } else if cardNum == 12 {
                    imageName = "card" + cardSuit + "Q"
                } else if cardNum == 13 {
                    imageName = "card" + cardSuit + "K"
                }
            }
        }
        
        return imageName
        
    }
    static func == (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return lhs.Suit() == rhs.Suit() && lhs.CardNum() == rhs.CardNum()
    }
    static func < (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return lhs.CardNum() < rhs.CardNum()
    }
    static func > (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return lhs.CardNum() > rhs.CardNum()
    }
    
    func Print() -> Void {
        print("\(self.cardNum) of \(self.cardSuit)")
    }
    func Suit() -> String {
        return self.cardSuit
    }
    func CardNum() -> Int {
        return self.cardNum
    }
    func PointValue() -> Int {
        return self.pointValue
    }
    func CardSuit() -> String {
        return self.cardSuit
    }
    func Equals(card:Card) -> Bool {
        if(self.CardNum() == card.CardNum()){
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
    func isSpecial() -> Bool {
        return specialCard
    }
    
};
```

I think the problem is something to do with observable objects.

Comment: There's way too much code here to go through, but at a quick glance, it looks like you have arrays of `Card` in many places. In `drawCard` to add to an array in `Player` but then you display an array in `HandModel`. Those two constructs don't know anything about each other.

Comment: Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app) 

I recommend you **do not nest** `ObservableObject`, make for example, `struct Card: Identifiable, Codable {...}`
and, do not have multiple arrays storing essencially the same data, eg, `var hand: [Card]?`, same with deck. Restructure your code, such that for example, you do not transfer a `Card` from one array to another,
 instead have a var that tells you the state of the card.

Comment: If you want to use view model, then make it right: view model should contain _all the data_ related to the view, but _never_ views themselves. So things like `GridItem` do not belong to view model, while the bunch of `@State` vars in your view are usually the ones placed in view model.

Comment: Hi, @workingdogsupportUkraine I've been trying to restructure my code to have a var that tells me the state of the card, but I do not know how to stop transferring the card from one array to another. For example how do I transfer a card from the deck to the player's hand by sampling updating its state?